# Access and read html/php page by https request by QML/js behind htaccess apache2 Server

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, qml

I have a home server with ssl / https and secured by htaccess.
I have configured the server in a way that, if I access

```
https://USER:PASSWORD@subdomain.domain.con/room_1/switch_1/set.php?state=0
```

the light in room 1 turns off. 
Further the page returns the current state very simple like

```
<html>
     0
</html>
```

Now I am trying to build an client application with QML (as it will support multiple plattforms).

The task should be to press a button and the app 'dials in' to

```
https://USER:PASSWORD@subdomain.domain.con/room_1/switch_1/set.php?state=0
```

and reads out the php page as plain string afterwards.

---

I tried from [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10029/how-can-i-send-http-request-from-qml/5) the XMLHttpRequest like

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/test/test.php");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    // what you want to be done when request is successfull
  }
}
req.onerror = function(){
  // what you want to be done when request failed
}

req.send("name=xxx&email=xxx&message=xxx");
```

in a Buttons onClicked-Event, but no response.

---

**Question**
Which way can realize this task???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED with
[Ignoring auto signed SSL certificates](https://lists.sailfishos.org/pipermail/devel/2013-November/001097.html)
and some basics for XMLHttpRequest.

**To handle an self signed (or any) SSL CA:**

Add these includes to main.cpp

```
#include <QSslConfiguration>
#include <QSslSocket>
```

Add these lines in beginning of your main()

```
QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

**To read files/responses by authorization via htaccess:**

The line 
"xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Qt.btoa(tb_user.text + ':' + tb_pw.text) )" 
was the key to correctly set the user and password.

```
function getSome() {
            txtLog.log("getSome executed");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

            xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://subdomain.domain.con/room_1/switch_1/set.php?state=0', true)
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Qt.btoa(tb_user.text + ':' + tb_pw.text) )
            xhr.withCredentials = true
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log( xhr.status, xhr.statusText )
                console.log( xhr.responseText , xhr.responseText )
            }
            xhr.send()
        }
```

---

**Sidenote for all Java Users:**

Yesterday I was able to create an Android Java app, which handles the task quite well. The problem with an self signed SSL CA is handled in the private void trustEveryone() function.

```
package com.home.me.myhome2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnOn;
    private Button btnOff;
    private TextView tv_test;

    private void trustEveryone() {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }});
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }}}, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                    context.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        trustEveryone();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);    

        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);
        tv_test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test);

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new PostClass().execute(new String[]{"https://subdomain.domain.con/room_1/switch_1/set.php?state=1"});
            }
        });

        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new PostClass().execute(new String[]{"https://subdomain.domain.con/room_1/switch_1/set.php?state=0"});
            }
        });
    }

    private class PostClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postOutput);
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);

                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                String urlParameters = "";
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");

                final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("USER:PASSWORD".getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Request Parameters " + urlParameters);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                final StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();

                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());

                HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        outputView.setText(output);
                        ;

                    }
                });

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```